What am I missing with SSRS report access? 3 users different outcomes
I have 3 users who needed access the SSRS url.  I added all 3 to SSMS security as well as SSRS (site/folder/all reports).  All are set as "browser."  Why do I have 3 different outcomes if all their credentials match?
User 1- can access all reports
User 2- can access the SSRS site but gets login loop when trying to access any report
User 3- gets stuck at the login loop immediately upon entering the url.
FYI- they are all using the same URL I sent to them. URL added as trusted and local intranet for each user.  Tried using Chrome and Edge. Nothing in the SSRS error log.
Any suggestions on where to look next would be much appreciated. Thank you!
